# Как в наследнике QListWidget, который переопределяет dropEvent, реализовать internalMove?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, drag-n-drop

```
#include "droplistwidget.h"
#include <QDropEvent>
#include <QMimeData>

DropListWidget::DropListWidget(QWidget *parent):
    QListWidget(parent)
{

}

void DropListWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    const QMimeData* d = event->mimeData();
    // есть ли данные?
    if (d->formats().isEmpty())
        return;

    // Получаем формат данных
    // Из другого QListWidget он будет таким "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"
    QString f = d->formats()[0];

    // Получаем данные, соответствующие данному формату
    QByteArray encoded = d->data(f);
    QDataStream stream(&encoded, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

    // Читаем данные
    while (!stream.atEnd())
    {
        int row, col;
        QMap<int,  QVariant> roleDataMap;
        stream >> row >> col >> roleDataMap;

        // roleDataMap хранит значения, соответствующие разным ролям
        // нам нужна роль Qt::DisplayRole - тексты итемов
        QString elementText = roleDataMap[Qt::DisplayRole].toString();

        // Проверям, если ли итемы с данным текстом
        bool flag = false; // Признак обнаружения копии (по имени)
        for (int i = 0; i < this->count(); i++) {
            if (item(i)->text().compare(elementText) == 0) {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // если не нашли, то добавляем новый элемент в список
        if (!flag) {
            QListWidget* sourceListWidget = dynamic_cast<QListWidget*>(event->source());
            // если источник это QListWidget
            if (sourceListWidget) {
                // Копируем иконку
                QIcon icon = sourceListWidget->item(row)->icon();
                // Создаем новый итем
                QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(icon, elementText);
                // добавляем
                addItem(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код наследника. А это то установка флагов.

```
    user_panel_buttons->setDragEnabled(true);
    user_panel_buttons->setAcceptDrops(true);
    user_panel_buttons->setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::InternalMove);
    user_panel_buttons->setDefaultDropAction(Qt::DropAction::CopyAction);
    user_panel_buttons->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
    //user_panel_buttons->setDragDropMode(QListWidget::DropOnly);
```

Comment: @Alexander Chernin.  Вы ответили на предыдущий мой вопрос, может и на этот знаете ответ?) Я не очень разбираюст в классах Qt. А точнее в классах Gui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно внести небольшие дополнения в `DropListWidget`.

Заголовник

```
class DropListWidget : public QListWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DropListWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
protected:
// Переопределяем метод "проникновения" драги
    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* event);
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent* event);
};
```

Реализация

```
// Проникновение
void DropListWidget::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    // Разрешаем любое проникновение (у курсора появится +)
    event->accept();

    // Если это перемещение, то вызываем метод предка - он знает, 
    // что с этим делать
    if (event->proposedAction() == Qt::MoveAction) {
        QListWidget::dragEnterEvent(event);
    }
}

// Небольшие дополнения в метод-событие "бросание"
void DropListWidget::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    //  если тип действия - перемещение, то
    if (event->dropAction() == Qt::MoveAction) {
        // Вызываем базовый метод, ибо ему виднее
        QListWidget::dropEvent(event);
    // А ежели это копирование, то все делаем как прежде
    } else if (event->dropAction() == Qt::CopyAction) {        
        const QMimeData* d = event->mimeData();

        // если ли данные?
        if (d->formats().isEmpty())
            return;

        // Получаем формат данных
        // Из другого QListWidget он будет таким "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"
        QString f = d->formats()[0];

        // Получаем данные, соответствующие данному формату
        QByteArray encoded = d->data(f);
        QDataStream stream(&encoded, QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        // Читаем данные
        while (!stream.atEnd())
        {
            int row, col;
            QMap<int,  QVariant> roleDataMap;
            stream >> row >> col >> roleDataMap;

            // roleDataMap хранит значения соответствующие разным ролям
            // нам нужна роль Qt::DisplayRole - тексты итемов
            QString elementText = roleDataMap[Qt::DisplayRole].toString();

            // Проверям, если ли итемы с данным текстом
            bool flag = false; // Признак обнаружения копии (по имени)
            for (int i = 0; i < this->count(); i++) {
                if (item(i)->text().compare(elementText) == 0) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // если не нашли, то вызываем базовый метод,
            // который добавит новый элемент в список
            if (!flag) {
                QListWidget* sourceListWidget = dynamic_cast<QListWidget*>(event->source());
                if (sourceListWidget) {
                    QIcon icon = sourceListWidget->item(row)->icon();
                    QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(icon, elementText);
                    addItem(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы это действительно по руководству поняли как сделать? Или имели опыт с классами Qt. Я насколько помню вообще классы Qt не переделывал. Поэтому , что у них внутри не знаю толком.